# How do I know if my websocket client is overwhelmed?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have a websocket client that receives 200-300 messages per second from a websocket stream. My JavaScript client that receives the messages is doing a few DOM manipulations with each message received. I'm afraid that after a few minutes of running the app in my browser, the processing of the messages could fall behind. Like a chat application that gets overwhelmed with incoming messages and after a while the latency between receiving the websocket message and displaying it to the user grows and grows... Another example would be a real-time stock market page, but after being open for a few minutes, the real-time prices aren't real-time anymore...

How do I determine if my browser is keeping up with the incoming websocket messages?

UPDATE

I ended up having every message update a clock on the page to see if it ever fell behind:

```
function onMessage(evt)
{
  var dt = new Date();
  $("#clock").text( dt.toLocaleTimeString() ); // "8:43:55 PM"

  // other DOM manipulations related to each websocket message ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how do you determine it when debugging, then you can look at your CPU utilization to see if you're swamping your CPU.

If you mean how to you determine it live from within your Javascript browser then I can think of some ideas:

1. Put a server time stamp in each message.  Then, when you start processing messages, calculate the diff between current system time and the time stamp in the message.  If that diff is going up and up, then the client is getting behind.  If it's staying relatively constant, then the client is keeping up.
2. You can give yourself some idea about how back-logged your server is with something like this:

code:

```
let start = Date.now();
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(Date.now() - start);
}, 0);
```

If that outputs a larger number, then your event queue is backed up some number of milliseconds.